# Advice needed on using a real time graph on rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

Just looking for some advice here on a small job I have to do. I’ve been asked to put together a page that displays a graph that updates in real time to show stats obtained from a remote server. It’s worth stating that this will be triggered on demand and will only capture data for a short time (e.g for 5 mins)

The app is based on rails 3 and I already have a class that will ssh to a target grab a value every 30 seconds and append that into an array that I’ll hold in a db table, I’ll use a background resque task to do this on demand

So what I’m looking for is some advice on the best way to display this array in a graph and update the graph data (i.e. grab the updated array from the db every 30 seconds.)

My first thought was to use something like Bluff http://bluff.jcoglan.com/ and just do a full page refresh but I wondered if I could do something nicer and use jQuery or Ajax to reach out and grab the array and refresh the graph in real time without doing a full page refresh.

If anyone has any ideas on the best way to do this I would really appreciate it. I’m fairly open to any suggestions on the best way to hold the data in the db or which graphing software I should use

Comment: could definately use ajax, take a look at http://www.highcharts.com/. A graphing framework. Plots anything you like and you can update the graph as you get more results

Comment: it's for a company system so cant use highlight due to licence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the end I used Flot graphs to write out the graph data

http://code.google.com/p/flot/

well worth checking out if you are doing any graphing work